# Angular 5 Router navigate from callback do nothing

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, router

I'm stuck on navigation from callback function, router.navigate do nothing.

I saw in stackoverflow that using NgZone may help but still no success, only thing which working is using window.location.href = 'url...'

but this is not angular functions and i really want to understand what wrong.

Here is my code.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      {path:'chat',component:ChatComponent},
      { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private zone: NgZone) { }

Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('email,user_birthday,user_friends', {
      success: function (user) {
        // Handle successful login
        console.log(user);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);

      },error: function (user, error) {
        // Handle errors and cancellation
      }
    });
```

Also tried like this ans still no success:

```
this.zone.runTask(()=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    })
```

Comment: Try with `this.zone.run` instead of `runTask`

Comment: already tried :( nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are loosing your context, try with a fat arrow in the callback.

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('email,user_birthday,user_friends', {
  success: (user) => {
    // Handle successful login
    console.log(user);
    this.router.navigate(['/']);

  },error: (user, error) => {
    // Handle errors and cancellation
  }
});
```

When you use a callback you must be sure that it will use your context, the current `this` should be your component, in typescript you will use the *fat arrow* operator (`=>`) that has the same effect of the vanilla js `function.bind(this)` to be sure that the code in the callback will use the right `this`, otherwise the `this`object of the callback will be the `window` object.

Comment: It is the solution, but hwy it acting like this?

Comment: I have updated the answer to give you a better explanation.